# アロー関数 ／ 1行にまとめても式がふたつ以上なら中カッコが必要？

Tags: ecmascript-6

下記リンク先で、以下のような記述があるのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？

```
// 1行にまとめても式がふたつ以上なら中カッコが必要
var add = (a, b) => console.log(a, b); a + b; // NG
var add = (a, b) => { console.log(a, b); a + b; } // OK
```

http://yoshiko-pg.github.io/slides/20150425-jsfes/#18

---

・試してみた限りでは、中カッコなくても大丈夫なような気もするのですが…
・仕様が変更されたのでしょうか？
・後に書いた方が先に実行される？

```
var a = 3;
var b = 4;
var add = (a, b) => console.log(a + b);console.log(a, b);
add(a,b); 
//3 4
//7
```

Comment: `;`　が文の区切りになりますので（一行に書くということは特別意味がありません、一行に複数の文があるというだけのことです）、{ } が必要です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

出力の順番を見てみると、うまくいっていないことがわかると思います。
質問文のコードは、要するに次のコードと同じです。

```
var a = 3;
var b = 4;
var add = (a, b) => console.log(a + b);
console.log(a, b);  // 3 4
add(a,b);           // 7
```